# Can anyone continue my step: $\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{z+x}+\frac{z}{x+y} +\frac{3xyz}{xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(z+x)}\geq 2.$

Tags: inequality

Let: $x,y,z>0$. Prove that: $$\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{z+x}+\frac{z}{x+y} +\frac{3xyz}{xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(z+x)}\geq 2.$$

I tried this:

WLOG, assume that: $x+y+z=3$ so get:

$$LHS \geq \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{3(xy+yz+zx)} + \frac{3xyz}{xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(z+x)}$$

Then put: $p=x+y+z=3,q=xy+yz+zx,r=xyz$ we need to prove:

$$\frac{9}{2q} + \frac{r}{q-r} \geq 2 (*)$$

But by AM-GM, get:
$$3=p \geq \sqrt[3]{r}\Leftrightarrow r \leq 1$$
so we get:
$$q \geq 3\sqrt[3]{r^2} >r^2 \geq r^3\Leftrightarrow r \leq q$$

Now $(*)$ can be rewritten as:$$9(q-r)+2qrt \geq 4q(q-r) \Leftrightarrow -4q^2+(8r+9)q-9r \geq 0$$

Then I put: $$f(q)=-4q^2+(8r+9)q-9r$$

and by Schur, I got: $$r \geq \frac{q(4p-p^2)}{9}=\frac{q}{3}$$

So now I need to prove: $f(q) \geq 0$ with $r \in [\frac{q}{3}; 1]$

Can anyone help me continue this step please!! Thank you a lots for your helps!

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: thanks for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*) is not true. In other words,
$\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{z+x}+\frac{z}{x+y}
\ge \frac{(x + y + z)^2}{x(y + z) + y(z + x) + z(x + y)}$ is not good enough.

We may use pqr for the original inequality.
The original inequality is written as
$$\frac{27 - 6q + 3r}{3q - r} + \frac{r}{q - r} \ge 2. \tag{1}$$

We split into two cases.

**Case 1**: $q \le \frac94$

We have
$$\mathrm{LHS}_{(1)}
\ge \frac{27 - 6q}{3q} = \frac{9}{q} - 2 \ge 2.$$

**Case 2**: $q > \frac94$

By degree four Schur inequality $r \ge \frac{5p^2q - p^4 - 4q^2}{6p}$, we have
$r \ge - \frac29q^2 + \frac52 q - \frac92
$. It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{27 - 6q + 3\cdot (- \frac29q^2 + \frac52 q - \frac92)}{3q - (- \frac29q^2 + \frac52 q - \frac92)} + \frac{- \frac29q^2 + \frac52 q - \frac92}{q - (- \frac29q^2 + \frac52 q - \frac92)} \ge 2$$
or
$$\frac{6q(3 - q)(4q - 9)^2}{(4q^2 + 9q + 81)(4q^2 - 27q + 81)} \ge 0$$
which is true using $p^2 \ge 3q$.

We are done.